# Enable Jayatana for Android Studio using commandline in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: command-line, java, android-studio

In Ubuntu 15.10 Jayatana is disabled by default. [There are several ways](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/10/ubuntu-1510-and-1504-update-disables.html) to enable it. And I would like enable Jayatana only for Android Studio, using command line. So I write in bash

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS"; /path/to/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

But it doesn't work: I don't get the usual `Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar` message and Global menu support doesn't work.

I have jayatana package installed on my system. So how do I enable Jayatana for Android Studio using command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do that. The correct command is

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS" /path/to/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

So I just had to remove the `;`

Comment: Thanks, the article at http://www.webupd8.org/2015/10/ubuntu-1510-and-1504-update-disables.html also mislead me, writing that as a line on its own above the startup command. Then I found the article at http://www.javahelps.com/2015/06/global-menu-support-for-java.html which suggests only inserting "-javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar" between the command "java -jar" and the rest of the java app startup command or startup script path. But I liked the one in your answer better.